# Java bitwise operation

Tags: java

I have this line of code

```
int b1 = 0xffff & (content[12]<<8 | 0xff & content[11]);
```

I have a bytearray (content[]) in little endian and need to recreate a 2 byte value. This code does the job just fine but prior to testing i had it written like this

```
int b1 = 0xffff & (content[12]<<8 | content[11]);
```

and the result was not right. My question is why is 0xff necessary in this scenario?

Comment: Because bytes are interpreted as signed integers, and this means, for example, that (byte) 0x80 gets (int) 0xffffff80. This is called sign extension.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `0xff` is necessary because of a confluence of two factors:

1. All integer types in Java are signed
2. All bitwise operators promote their arguments to `int` (or `long`, if necessary) before acting.

The result is that if the high-order bit of `content[11]` was set, it will be sign-extended to a negative `int` value. You need to then `&` this with `0xff` to return it to a (positive) byte value. Otherwise when you `|` it with the result of `content[12]<<8`, the high-order byte will be all 1s.

Comment: Thx for the reply! I would not have guessed content[11] would be casted to int with high-order bit set. I thought when i combine two values with OR they would be used AS ARE on the bit level. Cheers